# How to show image from database with eager loading?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to display multiple product image from database with eager loading, and when i tried to displaying it, console said `localhost:8000/storage/` `404 not found`. Any ideas how to solve this? this is my first time using eager loading & relationship on Laravel. Thank you!

Here is my controller :

```
public function homeProduct(){
  $products = Product::with('productCategory')->get();
  $images = Product::with('productImage')->get();

  return view('home.index', compact('products', 'images'));
}
```

Product Model :

```
public function productImage()
{
  return $this->hasMany(ProductImage::class, 'product_id', 'id');
}
```

Product Image Model :

```
public function product()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Product::class, 'id');
}
```

Here are the `index.blade.php` View :

```
@foreach ($products as $p)
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
       <div class="portfolio-thumb mb-5" data-aos="fade-up">
          <div id="yoreBeans" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
             <div class="carousel-inner">
                @foreach ($images as $key => $image)
                   <div class="carousel-item {{ $key == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">
                      <a href="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->path) }}" class="image-popup">
                         <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->path) }}" class="img-fluid portfolio-image" alt="">
                      </a>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
              </div>
             </div>
         <div class="portfolio-info">
             <h3 class="text-black">{{ $p->name }}</h3>
             <h4 class="text-danger">{{ $p->productCategory->name }}</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: did you run `php artisan storage:link`?

Comment: already did, and it still showing the error

Comment: also, when i didn't include the 'storage/' tag on asset, it doesn't show error but the image doesn't displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method `$images = Product::with('productImage')->get();` will also return Product objects with images.

What you exactly want is to eager load both realtions and then reference it at the same time:

```
public function homeProduct(){
    $products = Product::with(['productCategory', 'productImage'])->get();


    return view('home.index', compact('products'));
 }
```

And your view like this:

```
@foreach ($products as $p)
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-12">
       <div class="portfolio-thumb mb-5" data-aos="fade-up">
          <div id="yoreBeans" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
             <div class="carousel-inner">
                <!--  // this line changed  --->
                @foreach ($p->productImage as $key => $image) 
                   <div class="carousel-item {{ $key == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">
                      <a href="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->path) }}" class="image-popup">
                         <img src="{{ asset('storage/'.$image->path) }}" class="img-fluid portfolio-image" alt="">
                      </a>
                    </div>
                @endforeach
              </div>
             </div>
         <div class="portfolio-info">
             <h3 class="text-black">{{ $p->name }}</h3>
             <h4 class="text-danger">{{ $p->productCategory->name }}</h4>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
@endforeach
```